# Displacement Maps look pixelated in EEVEE

Tags: texturing, displacement, eevee-render-engine

When I add a displacement map to a UVd object in EEVEE the details look pixelated (although they look good in Cycles).

In EEVEE I have tried using subdivision surface modifiers and disabling half-res trace but the details still look pixelated. Am I using the wrong settings in 2.8 Beta or is there currently no quality settings at the moment because it is in Beta? I have added a screenshot showing what it looks like.

[image: EEVEE viewport]

Comment: Recommended reading: [**Cycles vs Eevee, 15 limitations on real time rendering**](https://cgcookie.com/articles/blender-cycles-vs-eevee-15-limitations-of-real-time-rendering)

Answer (score 2):

This is a known limitation as of Blender 2.80. Displacement maps aren’t truly supported. The displacement shaders will only affect the normals, not the actual vertex positions. Aka, it’s a bump map. And all bump maps in Eevee are currently limited to 2x2 pixels blocks, see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/limitations.html#materials

Comment: Thanks for the reply I appreciate it. Maybe one day we will get displacement in EEVEE Hopefully